# Configure HA Proxy between Apache and Tomcat servers

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy, high-availability, tomcat7, ajp

Want to configure HA Proxy with my existing structure. Currently I have Apache->Tomcat server. This I want to change to Apache->HA Proxy->Tomcat Server. HA I have configured for Http request. But my Apache works with AJP13.

Do I need to change

1) Apache to redirect with Http request? or

2) HA to accept AJP request(I don't know this can be achieve or not)?

I think 1st option is possible. Can any one suggest me how to achieve 1st Option? Also which one is the best way to do.

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy doesn't understand AJP13, only HTTP or TCP.

If you put HAProxy in `mode TCP` then you can load-balance requests to multiple Tomcat backends, but you loose the Layer7 features provided by `mode http`.

Answer (score 0):

HAproxy is used for distributing the load of one webpage between 2 identical web servers or as needed. Typically the load balancer will have the public IP then have Virtual IP's on the web hosts to send the traffic to. If you are trying to put apache in front of tomcat I don't believe HA is what you are looking for.

Comment: It means I have to go with HA Proxy->Multiple Apaches->Tomcat. Is it?